# Spring JPA doesn't work with Top and Pageable together

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jpql

I have a repository with a method name query to return the top 3 entities, e.g.

```
@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyEntity, Integer> {
    Page<MyEntity> findTop3By(Pageable pageable);
}
```

The method also supports a `Pageable` to give results pagination. However, the returned results do not respect the pageable size and are quite messed up. e.g. When there are 5 entities in total

```
myEntityRepository.findTop3By(PageRequest.of(0, 9))
// page 0 and size 9, got top 3 entities
// (good)

myEntityRepository.findTop3By(PageRequest.of(0, 4))
// page 0 and size 4, still got top 3 entities
// (good)

myEntityRepository.findTop3By(PageRequest.of(0, 3))
// page 0 and size 3, still got top 3 entities, however, returned TotalElements is 5
// (partial, expected TotalElements is 3 so that there is no next page)

myEntityRepository.findTop3By(PageRequest.of(1, 3))
// page 1 and size 3, got the 4th and 5th entities, returned TotalElements is 5 
// (wrong, expected no entities)

myEntityRepository.findTop3By(PageRequest.of(0, 2))
// page 0 and size 2, still got top 3 entities, returned TotalElements is 5
// (wrong, does not respect the page size, expected only the 1st and 2nd entities)

myEntityRepository.findTop3By(PageRequest.of(1, 2))
// page 1 and size 2, got 3rd, 4th and 5th entities, returned TotalElements is 5
// (wrong, expected only the 3rd entity)
```

How do you fix this to get the expected results?

Comment: I think you should use order by and pageable together, there is no need for top and pageable to be used together. Can you please tell us why you need query like this? Also I am very curious about how the real query generated by hibernate, can you also share these?

Comment: @Shawrup yes it is needed to control the page size and just showing the top results

Comment: @Shawrup its just `select ... from my_entity limit ?`

Comment: Both `Top` and `Pageale` will use the same construct (limit ?) or rowcount depending on the database. So that obviously won't work. Top3 already limits the number of results, if you only want to do sorting, just add `Sort` instead of `Pageable` to your method.

Comment: @M.Deinum No I need both. Say I have a page size of 5 and I am returning the top 10, I would like to see 5 at a time, not 10. So 5 in each page. You know, like those paginated table, 5 rows on a page.

Comment: You cannot as they both use the same mechanism (from a SQL perspective). The resulting query would (in both cases be something like ). `select * from your_table limit 10` (for a `findTop10` query method) and with a pageable it would be `select * from your_table LIMIT 0,10) to have the first page. So they are in the end the same mechanism. So if you want to limit the total results, you will have to check the pageable to not allow more results and you would have to do that in your controller/service by validating your input.

Comment: @user1589188 I agree with M.Deinum. Top and Pageable are mutually exclusive. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @M.Deinum Well the official document said both Top and Pageable together is supported https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko Its a paginated table with customisable page size and an option to return top N results. Say I want to see top 10 and my page size is 20, all good. If user wants to see less, say, 5 per page, user would reasonably expect the top 10 be returned across two pages.

Comment: If the docs say it is supported then either you are running into a bug or you aren't using a version that supports this (yet) as you point to the latest version of the docs (and not sure if your spring data jpa version is for that documentation).

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes I believe it may be a bug as I am on the latest version already. So please try to answer how to fix it giving the requirements.

Comment: Report a bug and wait for a new version.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have reported it. So in the meantime I can't just sit and wait, please let me know if you have alternative ways to workaround this?

Comment: Again it is a bug, if it would work as described you wouldn't ask the question. The workaround, write the queries yourself.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand is right, you need to paginate your repository query as well as sort the response. In that scenario, your repository should extends `PagingAndSortingRepository<MyEntity, Integer>`

```
public interface MyEntityRepository extends 
 PagingAndSortingRepository<MyEntity, Integer> {

    List<MyEntity> findAllByColumnName(String ColumnName, 
                                       Pageable pageable);
}
```

Then you have to create a `pageRequest`.

```
for(int pageCounter= 0; pageCounter < 100; ++i)
       Pageable PageRequestwithTopthree =
               PageRequest.of(pageCounter, 3, sort.by("column_name").descending());
}
```

**EDIT**

If you have a different page size, change it in pageRequest

```
Pageable PageRequestwithTopthree =
              PageRequest.of(pageCounter, pageSize, 
                              sort.by("column_name").descending());
```

Comment: But what if my pageSize is just 2, can't I get the 1st and 2nd on page 0 ant the 3rd on page 1?

Comment: Yes, please refer the edit. Pass the appropriate `pageSize` in `pageRequest`

Comment: I know, thats what I have done and I showed it in my question that this does not work.

Comment: Can you please share your repository code?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably define a method as follows (find all rows and then paginate them):

```
List<Foo> findAllByOrderBySomethingAsc(Pageable pageable)
```

Comment: Ummm, where is the Top then?

Comment: you can set pageSize = 3 thenit will show only top 3 , if you want next page just incement pageNumber.

Comment: But what if my pageSize is just 2, can't I get the 1st and 2nd on page 0 ant the 3rd on page 1?

Answer (score 0):

You should configure `Pageable` on the service layer this way

```
public Page<MyEntity> getTop3Page(int page, int size) {
    int topElementsNumber = 3;
    if(size > topElementsNumber) {
        size = topElementsNumber;
    }  
    
    List<MyEntity> content = getPageContent(page, size, topElementsNumber);
    return new PageImpl<>(content, pageable, topElementsNumber);
}

private List<MyEntity> getPageContent(int page, int size, int topElementsNumber) {
    int lastPage = getLastPage(size, topElementsNumber);

    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size);
    if(page > lastPage) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    Page<MyEntity> page = repository.findAll(pageable);

    int pageLastElementNumber = (page + 1) * size;
    if(pageLastElementNumber > topElementsNumber) {
        int sublistSize = size - (pageLastElementNumber - topElementsNumber);
        return page.getContent().subList(0, sublistSize);
    } 
    
    return page.getContent();
}

private int getLastPage(int size, int topElementsNumber) {
    int lastPage = (topElementsNumber / size) - 1;
    if(topElementsNumber % size > 0) {
        lastPage++;
    }

    return lastPage;
}
```

Comment: If I want size of 2, then on the 2nd page (page = 1, size = 2), it will return also the 4th entity, but I would expect only the 3rd on the 2nd page.

Comment: Hummm ok, I can see what you are trying to do here. You still retrieve the full size result but remove the extra entity if it is more than 3.

Comment: Can be useful for others, but I think it is not efficient.

Comment: To create a more suitable solution you need a custom repository. It can be a `Criteria api` query with subquery in **WHERE** - `where myEntity.id in(subquery)`

Answer (score 0):

Class PageRequest's constructor like follows

```
protected PageRequest(int page, int size, Sort sort)
```

we tend to pass a 'sort' for ordering by some regulation that you want.

Comment: document of Class sort is in this link [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.html)

Comment: Yes thank you. But the Sort is not required here.